# How can I set textbox focus for it data valid control?

Tags: vba, excel

I want check data validation in a textbox control and if not valid, return cursor in that textbox and not let user escape from.
But .setfocus method not work correctly and cursor will jump to another textbox after clicking in another or pressing Tab, when user entered not valid data, in initial textbox.

I tried this code:

```
Private Sub txtFirst_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Not IsNumeric(txtFirst.Text) Then
    lblStatusBar = "Error1"
    txtFirst = ""
    txtFirst.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If IsError(Application.Match(CInt(txtFirst.Value), Range("Table[Colulm1]"), 0)) Then
    lblStatusBar = "Error2"
    txtFirst.value=""
    txtFisrt.SetFocus
    exit sub
End If
lblStatusBar=""

End Sub
```

Can anyone correct?

Comment: One moment. Editing my answer

Comment: You may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: [Kostas K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7923463/kostas-k) Answer, solved my problem. (I haven't enough reputation to getting vote.)

Comment: try `Cancel = True` instead of `txtFirst.SetFocus`...

Comment: What is Cancel property?

Comment: No worries :) Glad your problem is solved

Comment: Thanks, for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Cancel the Exit operation by setting Cancel = True.

```
Private Sub txtFirst_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Not IsNumeric(txtFirst.Value) Then
        lblStatusBar = "Error1"
        txtFirst = ""
        txtFirst.SetFocus
        Cancel = True
        'exit sub  --> You dont need this here, the sub will exit anyway, 
        '              unless there's more code after "End If"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for your correction. What is "Cancel" property?

Comment: @user7878000 It's simply cancelling the control's Exit operation.

Comment: Whats the meaning of "cancelling the control's Exit operation"? is it related with exit sub?

Comment: No, each control raises two events: a) `Enter` when the control gets the focus (entering the control) and b) `Exit` just before the focus is moved to another control (exiting the control). Setting `Cancel = True` you cancel the exit operation so the focus remains in the control.

Comment: Very truly yours.

Comment: @user7878000 See my comment regarding `Exit Sub`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This uses `OERN (On Error Resume Next)` to check if an error was caused or not.

```
Private Sub txtFirst_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim Ret
    Dim rng As Range

    With txtFirst
        If Not IsNumeric(.Text) Then
            lblStatusBar = "Error1"
            .Value = ""
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

        On Error Resume Next
        '~~> Change Sheet1 to relevant sheet
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table[#Colulm1]")
        Ret = Application.Match(CInt(.Value), rng, 0)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            lblStatusBar = "Error2"
            .Value = ""
            Cancel = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess it's Sunday, so you're easy on the PO today. `Range("Table[#Colulm1]")` is missing the Worksheet, we're ok with assuming it's `ActiveSheet` ?

Comment: That problem not serious and is in #. I should remove # for set range in a specific column. in this question, major problem is in set focus and force user to enter valid data, before escape from a textbox

Comment: @ShaiRado: No. We should not be ok assuming that it's activesheet. :)

Comment: @user7878000: ensure that your range object is fully qualified. For example `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Blah Blah")` Also is `Colulm1` a typo? Did you give the above code a try?

Comment: Please review the main question. I was correct that and remove the part you discuss about!

Comment: @ShaiRado: Your suggestion has been incorporated. :)

Comment: Defined range in questions code, works correctly, because code called from related sheet.